# Read Access Violation in assembly code

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

Here is a simple asm code I have inserted in VC++ project. return_addr is the return address of the stack frame. I have a StackWalk function (not been written by me codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) which uses StackWalk64() to extract the frames. Details of this are not relevant. Using the return address I extract a single byte from the code of the function in the stack currently being examined.

```
__asm{
       push eax
       push ecx

       mov eax, return_addr

       mov cl, BYTE PTR [eax - 5]  //Problem Statement
       mov ret_5, cl  

       pop ecx
       pop eax
}
```

I run my code along with other applications like gtalk, vlc etc. The application always crashes when I include the Problem Statement. When I remove these statements everything works fine. I ran a debugger and it breaks at Problem Statement showing an Access Violation reading location 0xzzzzzz error. I suppose the application is trying to read the code of some restricted dll or code section and that raises an error. I used a try catch block but that didn't help. Any suggestions as to what I can do?

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "return address of the stack frame"? Seems likely that is the core issue you are having.

Comment: 0xzzzzzz? How about posting the ACTUAL address?

Comment: @Jonathan: Each stack frame has a return address where the control is transfered once the function terminates. It is inside the caller function.

Comment: @Jens: The error occurs for a variety of addresses like 0x45f89cf, 0xe8187789...

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that whatever the `return_addr` value is, it does't point to a valid memory location, because otherwise the access violation wouldn't occur. So the details of that are very relevant.

Comment: The return_addr contains a valid value. I log all the data and in the log file I get valid values of ret_5 but for some values of return_addr (see above), the program crashes. The base address of googletalk module is 0x400000. So these addresses look a little suspicious.